# David Chaum's anonymous credential

Tags: public-key, authentication, anonymity, data-privacy

I am a newbie in cryptography (I know the basic RSA, AES stuffs) and am interested in anonymous authentication systems. Looks like David Chaum is the godly figure in the field. I see lots of people citing his [anonymous credential system paper](http://oai.cwi.nl/oai/asset/1745/1745A.pdf)  and [his 
paper](http://chaum.com/publications/Security_Wthout_Identification.html).

Can someone explain in simple language (and simple maths), the concept behind David Chaum's anonymous credential system? I find the papers too heavy to understand. I probably have lots of follow up questions.

Comment: "Security without Identification" is the best part, I believe, to start from. It explains the concept, in simple language and simple math. Yes, it still could be heavy.